# Javascript round function does not work

Tags: javascript

I have a function in JavaScript that rounds numbers.

```
function roundNumber(num){
    var result = Math.round(num*100)/100;
    return result;
}

alert(roundNumber(5334.5));

//I still get 5334.5 when normally I should get 5335
```

What am I missing?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HwvX2/

Comment: You're dividing the result by 100. Why are you expecting that to be an integer?

Comment: Your function is a way to truncate to 2 decimal places, but you are expecting to get it to round to the nearest whole number.  Bit of a logical error here.

Comment: You appear to be using code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-javascript which rounds to two decimal places

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use:

```
function roundNumber(num){
    var result = Math.round(num);
    return result;
}

alert(roundNumber(5334.5));
```

Comment: Directly using `Math.round()` makes more sense to me... just saying.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
alert(Math.round(5334.5));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HwvX2/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct. You are in effect rounding to 2 decimal places. Should be:

```
Math.round(num);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of those times where you want to override the default behaviour, Math.round is a great method but sometimes that wheel just isn't round enough. Here's what you could do:

```
Math.round = function (x) {
      if (parseInt((x + 0.5).toString().split(".")[0], 10) > parseInt(x.toString().split(".")[0], 10)) {
              return parseInt((x + 1).toString().split(".")[0], 10);
       } else {
              return parseInt(x.toString().split(".")[0], 10);
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use right brackets :

```
 var result = Math.round(num);
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/tibo/1/

Comment: Why do you multiply by `100` and then divide by `100`?

Comment: @DaniloValente : OP's original question.. I just copied the same.. Need a coffeee.. arg..:)

Answer (score 0):

should be `Math.round((num*100)/100)`

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your codes with this line ::

```
       var result = Math.round(num);
```